# opencv Python face recognizer.load

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem with face detection.

**code:**

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

path = 'dataSet'
cascadePath = "Classifiers/face.xml"

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.load('trainer/trainer.yml')
```

**AttributeError:**

```
'cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute 'Load'
```

Help me, I already researched and still have not found an answer.

I am using `python` 3.6.1 and `opencv` 3.0

Comment: Im pretty sure if you are using OpenCV3 that it has been deprecated, I don't know what the solution is though

Comment: i am use python 3.6.1 and opencv 3.0

Comment: @GPPK OpenCV 3 is definitely *not* deprecated.

Comment: @cwallenpoole not opencv3, LBPHFaceRecognizer class. I think it's been replaced and can only be used in Opencv2. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it doesn't have that property. You mean `read`.

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
```

Here's the help:

```
 |  read(...)
 |      read(filename) -> None
 |      .   @brief Loads a FaceRecognizer and its model state.
 |      .
 |      .   Loads a persisted model and state from a given XML or YAML file . Every FaceRecognizer has to
 |      .   overwrite FaceRecognizer::load(FileStorage& fs) to enable loading the model state.
 |      .   FaceRecognizer::load(FileStorage& fs) in turn gets called by
 |      .   FaceRecognizer::load(const String& filename), to ease saving a model.
```